# Call gulp from Web Worker

Tags: javascript, gulp, web-worker

I'm trying to execute Gulp from a Web Worker, in particular with child_process that let me execute terminal command from Javascript. But I could not load the module with require. This is the question I have open for that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495147/user-child-process-inside-web-worker

So my question here is how can I execute Gulp from a Web Worker?